# Adding a custom Wordpress widget crashes the Media Library

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, advanced-custom-fields

Im creating a custom Wordpress theme and recently the Media Library stopped working. I'm using ACF to create custom fields, and when I want to select an image the Media Library just keeps loading without showing any images.

After some debugging I noticed that when removing the code that adds my custom widget, everything works fine.

Now, my question is, how does the code below affect the functionality of the Media Library?

```
<!-- 

This widget is created to display some simple business information like a phone number and an address.
If supplied the widget will also show icons for social medias such as Facebook, Instagram and Twitter.

 -->
<?php 

class info_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(

            // Base ID of your widget
            'info_widget', 

            // Widget name will appear in UI
            __('Information Widget', 'wpb_widget_domain'), 

            // Widget description
            array( 'description' => __('Simple widget to display some business information.', 'wpb_widget_domain' )) 
        );
    }

    // Creating widget front-end
    public function widget($args, $instance) {

        // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['before_widget'];

        // This is where you run the code and display the output

        $phone = __($instance['phone'], 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        $address = __($instance['address'], 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        $facebook_link = __($instance['facebook_link'], 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        $twitter_link = __($instance['twitter_link'], 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        $youtube_link = __($instance['youtube_link'], 'wpb_widget_domain' );

        ?>

        <style type="text/css">

            .widget_info_widget {
                height: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

                .widget_info_widget .wrapper {
                    flex-grow: 1;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    justify-content: center;
                }

                    .widget_info_widget .wrapper p {
                        margin: 5px;
                    }

                    .widget_info_widget .wrapper a {
                        color: black;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    .widget_info_widget .wrapper a:hover {
                        text-decoration: underline;
                    }

                    .widget_info_widget .wrapper .icons {
                        margin-top: 20px;
                    }

                        .widget_info_widget .wrapper .icons .social {
                            font-size: 30px;
                            transition: filter 250ms;
                            color: black;
                            margin-left: 5px;
                            margin-right: 5px;
                        }

                        .widget_info_widget .wrapper .icons .social:hover {
                            filter: invert(0.5);
                        }


        </style>

        <center class="wrapper">

            <p class="phone-number"><?php echo $phone; ?></p>
            <p class="address"><a href="https://www.google.se/maps/place/<?php echo $address?>"><?php echo $address; ?></a></p>

            <div class="icons">
                <?php if (!empty($facebook_link)): ?> 
                    <a class="social" href="<?php echo $facebook_link; ?>"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (!empty($twitter_link)): ?> 
                    <a class="social" href="<?php echo $twitter_link; ?>"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (!empty($youtube_link)): ?> 
                    <a class="social" href="<?php echo $youtube_link; ?>"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </center>





        <?php
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    // Widget Backend 
    public function form($instance) {

        if (isset($instance['phone'] ) ) {
            $phone = $instance['phone'];
        }
        else {
            $phone = __('070-123 45 67', 'wpb_widget_domain');
        }

        if (isset($instance['address'] ) ) {
            $address = $instance['address'];
        }
        else {
            $address = __('Templateroad 5', 'wpb_widget_domain');
        }

        if (isset($instance['facebook_link'] ) ) {
            $facebook_link = $instance['facebook_link'];
        }
        if (isset($instance['twitter_link'] ) ) {
            $twitter_link = $instance['twitter_link'];
        }
        if (isset($instance['youtube_link'] ) ) {
            $youtube_link = $instance['youtube_link'];
        }

        // Widget admin form
        ?>

            <style type="text/css">
                .widefat {
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                }
            </style>

            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('phone'); ?>"><?php _e('Phone:'); ?></label> 
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('phone'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('phone'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($phone); ?>" />

                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('address'); ?>"><?php _e('Address:'); ?></label> 
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('address'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('address'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($address); ?>" />

                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('facebook_link'); ?>"><?php _e('Facebook Link (not required):'); ?></label> 
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('facebook_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('facebook_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($facebook_link); ?>" />

                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('twitter_link'); ?>"><?php _e('Twitter Link (not required):'); ?></label> 
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('twitter_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('twitter_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($twitter_link); ?>" />

                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('youtube_link'); ?>"><?php _e('Youtube Link (not required):'); ?></label> 
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('youtube_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('youtube_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($youtube_link); ?>" />
            </p>
        <?php 
    }

    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';
        $instance['phone'] = (!empty($new_instance['phone'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['phone']) : '';
        $instance['address'] = (!empty($new_instance['address'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['address']) : '';
        $instance['facebook_link'] = (!empty($new_instance['facebook_link'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['facebook_link']) : '';
        $instance['twitter_link'] = (!empty($new_instance['twitter_link'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['twitter_link']) : '';
        $instance['youtube_link'] = (!empty($new_instance['youtube_link'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['youtube_link']) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
}

?>
```

The code in my functions.php file to load the widget looks like this:

```
// Custom info widget

// Register and load the widget
function load_widget() {
    register_widget('info_widget');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'load_widget');

include 'widgets/information_widget.php';
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and I'm relatively new to Wordpress so I might have missed something obvious but it just seems odd that the Media Library stops working..
It should also be noted that the widget itself works properly, both backend and frontend!

Comment: I mean that your widget ist not the problem. On the media back end screen WP don't load the widgets. Maybe you should lock inside the console of the browser or get error message in the javascript context. Also read the error log of the server to get valid error messages.

Comment: Never mind, i solved it, apparently it was the comment at the top of the .php file that contained the widget that caused the problem. FYI, there was no console errors when loading the Media Library, it just didn't load. Anyway, it works now!